# Sharing Models between ScriptSharp and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, postsharp

I would like to share my scriptsharp models with MVC to use strongly typed JSON response from my controllers to the javascript code and vise versa.
There is a post about it but it doesn't seems to work
[Old post about the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280755/share-code-between-website-web-application-project-and-script-scriptsharp)

my problem is that i decorate the members in the model class with [PreserveCase]. this is part of the postsharp mscorlib.dll which i cannot reference in my MVC project. so adding links to the model class on the MVC project solution doesn't work.

What would be the best way to share models between postSharp and MVC?

Noam

Comment: Are you asking how to get aspects into your MVC project without referencing the PostSharp libraries? Why are you not able to make the reference?

Answer (score 1):

check this out,

http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/dotnet/json-enabled-wcf-services-part-2/

I was able to build something similar and it works like a charm.  whether you use WCF or MVC, the theory for sending JSON around should be the same.